# Eliminar un array de objetos duplicados en javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo eliminar datos duplicados de un array de objetos?:

ejemplo:

```
var array = [
  {id:1,nombre:'casa'},
  {id:2,nombre:'fruta'},
  {id:3,nombre:'mascotas'},
  {id:1,nombre:'casa'},
  {id:2,nombre:'fruta'},
  {id:4,nombre:'cosas'},
  {id:5,nombre:'otros'}
];
```

Comment: ¿eso es un json?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aquí tienes [soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) que podrían ser útiles para tu Array.

Prueba de esta forma:

```
var arrayWithDuplicates = [
    {"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"NV"},
    {"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "A7846", state:"CA"},
    {"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"OR"},
    {"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "10849", state:"CA"},
    {"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "B7037", state:"WA"},
    {"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"NM"}
];

function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
     var newArray = [];
     var lookupObject  = {};

     for(var i in originalArray) {
        lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
     }

     for(i in lookupObject) {
         newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
     }
      return newArray;
 }

var uniqueArray = removeDuplicates(arrayWithDuplicates, "licenseNum");
console.log("uniqueArray is: " + JSON.stringify(uniqueArray));
```

También puedes probar así:

```
var arr = {};

for ( var i=0, len=things.thing.length; i < len; i++ )
    arr[things.thing[i]['place']] = things.thing[i];

things.thing = new Array();
for ( var key in arr )
    things.thing.push(arr[key]);
```

Comment: no puede ser duplicada por que esa pregunta pertenece a SOen

Comment: Gracias Rene, aclarado, edito.

Comment: La próxima vez intenta adecuar el código al problema planteado, no simplemente copies y pegues de la respuesta de otros.

Comment: Tienes razón Marcos, veo más adecuada tu respuesta.

Comment: Aún puedes [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/41203/edit) tu respuesta y acomodar el código al problema.

Answer (score 19):

Podrías usar [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) (`IE9+`)

Ejemplo:

```js
var array = [
  {id:1,nombre:'casa'},
  {id:2,nombre:'fruta'},
  {id:3,nombre:'mascotas'},
  {id:1,nombre:'casa'},
  {id:2,nombre:'fruta'},
  {id:4,nombre:'cosas'},
  {id:5,nombre:'otros'}
];

var hash = {};
array = array.filter(function(current) {
  var exists = !hash[current.id];
  hash[current.id] = true;
  return exists;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

---

Usando **ES6**

```js
var array = [
  {id:1,nombre:'casa'},
  {id:2,nombre:'fruta'},
  {id:3,nombre:'mascotas'},
  {id:1,nombre:'casa'},
  {id:2,nombre:'fruta'},
  {id:4,nombre:'cosas'},
  {id:5,nombre:'otros'}
];

let hash = {};
array = array.filter(o => hash[o.id] ? false : hash[o.id] = true);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: se puede usar para resolver este problema la estructura de datos SET, pero no logro implementarlo, puedes dar un ejemplo con SET?

Comment: no, me refiero a SET de js, aqui su documentacion https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: @Marcos genial, funcionó excelente tu código pero, exactamente cómo funciona la parte de hash[o.id] ? false : hash[o.id] = true? No me queda muy claro

Comment: @ChristianAlvarenga es un condicional en línea, significa: Si `hash[o.id]` es `truly`, entonces devuelvo `false` (_esta repedito_), sino, devuelvo (_y asigno_) `hash[o.id] = true`.

Comment: @Marcos Comprendo, gracias por tu aclaración!

Answer (score 4):

Se podría usar el objeto [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set)

> Los objetos Set son colecciones de valores. Se puede iterar sus elementos en el orden de su inserción. Un valor en un Set sólo puede estar una vez; éste es único en la colección Set.

```js
let array = [
  { id: 1, nombre: 'casa' },
  { id: 2, nombre: 'fruta' },
  { id: 3, nombre: 'mascotas' },
  { id: 1, nombre: 'casa' },
  { id: 2, nombre: 'fruta' },
  { id: 4, nombre: 'cosas' },
  { id: 5, nombre: 'otros' }
];

let set                 = new Set( array.map( JSON.stringify ) )
let arrSinDuplicaciones = Array.from( set ).map( JSON.parse );

console.log( arrSinDuplicaciones );
```