# ¿Cómo eliminar objetos duplicados de una array de objetos en javascript?

Tags: javascript

En mi caso tengo un array  de objetos con :

```js
array = [
  { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 200 },
  { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 125 },
  { IdModeloS: 1},
  { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 200 },
  { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 200 },
  { IdModeloS: 1},
  { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 200 },
  { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 125 },
  { IdModeloS: 7},
  { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 200 },
  { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 200 },
  { IdModeloS: 7}];
```

y quiero obtener otro array sin los objetos duplicados del array como este:

```js
arrayOrdenado = [
      { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 200 },
      { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 125 },
      { IdModeloS: 1},
      { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 200 },
      { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 125 },
      { IdModeloS: 7}];
```

Todo lo que he encontrado hasta ahora comparaba un solo elemento del array. Estoy buscando algo que compare todo el conjunto. En mi caso IdModeloS y Cilindrada.

He probado alguna cosa, pero no consigo comparar todos los objetos del array.
He probado lo siguiente:

```js
  var isEqualFunction = function (a, b) {
    return a.IdModeloS === b.IdModeloS && a.Cilindrada === b.Cilindrada;
  }
  var compareFunction = function (a, b) {
    return a.IdModeloS === b.IdModeloS ? (a.Cilindrada === b.Cilindrada ? 0 : (a.Cilindrada < b.Cilindrada ? -1 : 1)) : (a.IdModeloS < b.IdModeloS ? -1 : 1);
  }
  var arrayOrdenado = array.sort(compareFunction);
  var repetidos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOrdenado.length - 1; i++) {
      if (isEqualFunction(arrayOrdenado[i + 1], arrayOrdenado[i])) {
          arrayOrdenado.splice(i,1);
      }
  }
```

Se han  eliminado los objetos duplicados una vez, pero no elimina los objetos que están duplicados varias veces.

Comment: He estado buscando y solo he encontrado casos en los que se compara un elemento de cada objeto. No he encontrado casos en los que se comparen todos los elementos de los objetos del array.

Comment: Bueno, a partir de una idea puedes tú implementar la comparacion de todos. Y en caso de que no te resultara, puedes preguntar tus dudas concretas aqui mostrando datos de ejemplo, lo que has probado y los errrores concretos que hacen que no consigas el resultado esperado. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el ejemplo que daba @marcos en la pregunta [enlazada como duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41202/eliminar-un-array-de-objetos-duplicados-en-javascript) podría haberte servido.

Haciendo uso del array auxiliar `hash`, que no es más que un array asociativo, podemos combinar como nombres de clave el identificador `IdModeloS` y la `Cilindrada`, si existe. Y para comprobar si existe dicha combinación, simplemente asignar el valor **true** cuando aparece, y devolver la variable `exists` que contiene el valor del susodicho array (o **false**, si no hay ninguno).

```js
  array = [
    { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 200 },
    { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 125 },
    { IdModeloS: 1},
    { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 200 },
    { IdModeloS: 1, Cilindrada: 200 },
    { IdModeloS: 1},
    { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 200 },
    { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 125 },
    { IdModeloS: 7},
    { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 200 },
    { IdModeloS: 7, Cilindrada: 200 },
    { IdModeloS: 7}];
    

var hash = {};
array = array.filter(function(current) 
{
  let go = current.Cilindrada !== undefined ? String(current.IdModeloS) + String(current.Cilindrada) : String(current.IdModeloS);
  
  let exists = !hash[go] || false;
   
  hash[go] = true;
  
  return exists;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```