# Convertir un String en varios String separados por coma dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy recibiendo un Array (`div`) con un solo String y quiero que me imprima lo siguiente `A,B,C,D` , osea, que me convierta ese String en en varios string dentro del array y luego lo ordene y quite duplicados.

```
Array.prototype.unique=function(a){
  return function(){return this.filter(a)}}(function(a,b,c){return 
c.indexOf(a,b+1)<0;
});

var div = ["'D','B,'C','A','B'"];

var f = div.join();//.unique().sort().join().slice(0, -1);

var filtroDiv = [f.slice(0, -1)];

console.log(filtroDiv); //["'A','B,'C','D','B"]
```

Comment: y cual es tu duda en lo que planteas?

Comment: Me imprime esto `["'A','B,'C','D','B"]` y necesito que me imprima `A,B,C,D ` quiero que me quite las comillas, me las ordene y quite duplicado

Comment: Porque usas las `"` del principio y del final al crear el array ?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Eliminar un array de objetos duplicados en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41202/eliminar-un-array-de-objetos-duplicados-en-javascript)

Comment: Lamentablemente asi la obtengo de una base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
var div = ["'D','B','C','A','B'"]
div = div[0].replace(/[-+'/\s]/g, '').split(',') // Array(5) ['D','B','C','A','B']
uniques = (valor, indice, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(valor) === indice;
}
filtrado = div.filter(uniques)
console.log(filtrado) // Array(4) ['D','B','C','A']
```

Espero esta respuesta este más correcta y te pueda ayudar.
Te añado una imagen para que veas el resultado del código.

[image: Código y resultado de ejecutar este mismo.]

Comment: También se pregunta por eliminar repetidos y ordenar.

Comment: No funciona, si observas los valores de `div` vienen dentro de comillas simples

Comment: Ya he solucionado el error que cometí, creo que mi respuesta soluciona el problema totalmente.